# Android изменение xml атрибутов через Java

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер

Как менять xml атрибуты макетов через Java код android? Вначале подумал об использовании регулярных выражений, но мне сказали, что "парсить регулярками хтмл или хмл это чистейшее зло", поэтому я решил спросить, может есть адекватная библиотека/решение этой задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для настраивания макета можно использовать код в том числе. Все необходимые классы и методы уже реализованы, вам не нужно постоянно менять xml - просто в нужное время вызываете нужные методы.

Такие классы как `LayoutParams`(внутренний класс), `LayoutInflater` и тд.

Все, что вам нужно - найти в документации необходимые инструменты в виде кода.